# SpotifyAPI. C#. Как сделать запрос на artist & song name

Tags: c#, api

Начал разбираться с SpotifyAPI, но на оф сайте ничего не понимаю.
(https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/search/search/)
Задача такая: есть входная строка (title) в котором хранится например - "Bring Me The Horizon - Throne"

Хочу заснуть эту строку в запрос и что бы тот мне вернул отдельно имя исполнителя и название трэка.

Может кто-нибудь уже работал с этим и знает как делать?

Comment: А что не понятного? Ведь обычный API, где отправляется GET запрос с нужным искомым текстом и типом, а в заголовках ключ авторизации. Сами то что пробовали?

Comment: Я использовал клиент с GitHub - https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET, чтобы не создавать свой.
Но я не могу найти мануалы по его использованию. Там есть примеры (логирование, и т.п.), но я не могу их понять.

Comment: А на оф сайте, просто показывается какой синтаксис запроса должен быть, но я не понимаю как это в шарпе должно выглядеть. Даже не знаю как найти ответы.
Гуглил но ничего с search не нашел (возможно я не умею пользоваться гуглом :( )

Comment: Зачем вам огромная библиотека для отправки одного запроса? Берите `HttpClient` и отправляйте GET запрос как показано в инструкции, не надо велосипеды изобретать!

Comment: Вы бы не могли скинуть мануал или туториал как нужно инициализировать HttpClient в шарпе, и как с помощью него отправлять get запросы?
Потому что я вообще не понимаю ничего(
(И я вот смотрю на search, там есть разные field filters, но у меня просто строка в которой я не знаю что есть что - где artist name, а где song name, смогу ли я вообще получить то что мне нужно?)

Comment: Как же вы планируете дальше программировать, если не можете сделать базовые вещи? Вот пишу я в гугле `HttpClient c#`, сразу вижу первой ссылку на [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) с примером как именно отправлять GET запросы, остается только задать заголовок с ключом. Попробуйте сами, это просто! И хватит придуряться и делать вид, что вы нечего не знаете и не умеете, это не так, я уверен что вам по силам данная задача! Вот я дам вам ответ, и? Вы через пол часа прибежите сюда с другим вопросом и будете опять просить сделать за вас, оно надо?